# jsreport-core how add localization?

Tags: jsreport

Consider the following example: https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/VkLWfMyMb-7

I was able to recreate this using jsreports-online. How can I add localization to jsreport-core?

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {

    jsreport().init().then((reporter: Reporter) => {
        const templatePath: string = path.join(__dirname, 'assets', 'template.html');
        const template: string = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf8');

        const exampledatapath: string = path.join(__dirname, 'assets', 'exampledata.json');
        const exampledata: string = fs.readFileSync(exampledatapath, 'utf8');

        let data = JSON.parse(exampledata);

        reporter.render({
            template: {
                content: template,
                engine: 'handlebars',
                recipe: 'chrome-pdf',
            },
            data: data
        }).then(function (out: any) {
            out.stream.pipe(res);
        })
            .catch(function (e: any) {
                res.end(e.message);
            });
    }).catch(function (e: any) {
        res.end(e.message);
    });
});
```

Best I could come up with is something like this `data['$localizedResource'] = {key1: 'value1'};`

Is there a better or build-in way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You better handle localization on your own in such a case.

Using the [resources extension](https://jsreport.net/learn/resources) with jsreport-core would require to install additional extension [data](https://jsreport.net/learn/inline-data). Insert resources to the documents store, reference it in the template call...

I see you are anyway sending the template content manually, not using the store. In this case, you better to store your localized files inside plain json, read them using nodejs and extend the input data with it.

```js
reporter.render({
  template: {
    content: template,
    engine: 'handlebars',
    recipe: 'chrome-pdf',
  },
  data: {
    ...data,
    $localizedResource: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('....mylabels-en.json').toString())
  }
}
```